# What is the limit for no of subscriptions for a pubsub node in ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I can see the subscription list in ejabberd odbc setup is a TEXT, what is the normal limit on number of subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fix limit on the number of pubsub subscriptions on a single node in ejabberd. It depends on many parameters like server specifications, ejabberd configuration, backend used, pubsub configuration, pubsub plugin used. etc.

As I understand it, the question is about the limit in your specific situation, so my advice would be to benchmark the platform with a tool like Tsung to validate the overall scalability of your platform.